# What is a "case," used in grocery stores, in Spanish?

Tags: vocabulario, vocabulario-técnico

In grocery stores in the US, the following things are known as "cases" of different kinds:

- Some are refrigerated but have no glass or doors, so that customers can select what they want directly:

  > [image]
- Others have glass on the front, so only employees can access the products (from the back):

  > [image]
- Others have doors that the customers can open:

  > [image]

My understanding is that the Spanish word [***vitrina***](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=vitrina) can be used as a translation of "display case," but it appears to me that its use is normally limited to cases that have glass on the front.  If that's true, then *vitrina* could only be used to describe the second and third images above.

What is the term used in the grocery industry to describe these types of cases, especially the first image above?  I'm particularly interested in what vocabulary would be used in Mexico and Latin America generally, if that matters.

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't use *vitrina* for any of those. A *vitrina* is either a [piece of furniture for display purposes](http://www.gomodern.co.uk/store/files/large-product-images/GM-MEND-01-1-large.jpg), as what you may find in a museum, or a [window shop](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/HK_Central_IFC_Mall_interior_evening_shop_window_female_clothing_model_Feb-2013.JPG). It would be a bit of a stretch to call the second one a *vitrina*, and not appropriate for the third one. [This](http://www.lincat.co.uk/uploads/category/Images/GC46D.jpg) would come closer to a *vitrina*.

Comment: BTW, my previous comment applies to Spain.

Comment: FWIW, I've seen all three called _vitrina refrigerada_ in Chile.

Answer (score 6):

En España la primera imagen y la tercera imagen se llaman frigorífico.

La segunda lo llamaría mostrador.

Comment: Similar en Colombia, pero a las tres imágenes en lugar de frigorífico les decimos "**enfriador**"

Answer (score 5):

They are *vitrinas* because they have windows and are for display purposes. You have to add de adjetive *refrigerador*

Searching in the web pages of companies that sell them, I see that the word most used for the third one is *armario refrigerador*

Comment: In Chile: _vitrina refrigerada_.

Comment: In Argentina, it would be an _heladera exhibidora_.

Comment: We also use vitrinas in Colombia.

Answer (score 4):

In Peru we use "exhibidora", for cases used in supermarket

for this:

[image: góndola]

I heard "góndola" or "góndola refrigerada"

Answer (score 1):

### Expositor

4. m. Mueble en que se expone algo a la vista del público, generalmente para su venta.

<sub>*[RAE](https://dle.rae.es/expositor#MsbYKll)*</sub>

### Góndola

3. f. expositor (‖ mueble).

<sub>*[RAE](https://dle.rae.es/g%C3%B3ndola)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In México you could call all of them as *refrigerador*. Like in the USA the refrigerated items are grouped together in a zone; we call it *zona de refrigeradores* or *área de refrigeradores*.

However, if you need to be more specific, these are the terms used.

photo 1)
- *Estante frío* or *estante refrigerado* (because it doesn't have a glass on the front)

photo 2)
- *Vitrina* (opposite as photo 1), can also be regarded as *vitrina refrigerada*

photo 3)
- *Refrigerador*.

The case in the third photo it's also a *vitrina* but we call it *refrigerador* because of the rectangular prism form. You could call it *refrigerador vitrina* but is almost redundant because if it's inside a grocery store, it is expected to have a glass door.